# MongoDB - Not Authorized to Execute Command

Tags: mongodb, shell, authentication, roles, createuser

I have successfully enabled authorization on MongoDB and I have created an account on the admin database and then I created an account for my database called test. The following connection string to connect to my test database works successfully: `mongo --host 192.168.17.52 --port 27017 -u user1 -p password --authenticationDatabase test`

Only problem I have now is, I cannot execute commands such as: show dbs. I get the following error when I try to do so:

```
"errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"a1d5bc0d-bc58-485e-b232-270758a89455\") }, $db: \"admin\" }"
```

I have been on many online sources to help fix this issue but no luck, is there a way to resolve this issue? Seems like my user can't access the admin database, is there a way to grant this access to my user so I can run the necessary commands like show dbs?

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: what role did you assign to the user? (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

Comment: @MetalMad Thank you for the response, here are the roles I have applied to the user, roles: ["dbAdmin", "read", "readWrite", "dbOwner", "userAdmin"]

Answer (score 4):

In order to run `show dbs` command and if the user has access to multiple databases, first the user should be created on the `admin` database (this is because `listDatabases` action is a cluster wide operation). Also the user should be given access to this operation. In order to do that, a new role should be created with the action. Below are the steps for the same:

//login as `admin` with `--authenticationDatabase "admin"` (assumption is that `admin` user is with `root` privileges) and then run the below:

```
use admin;

db.runCommand({ createRole: "listDatabases", privileges: [{ resource: { cluster : true }, actions: ["listDatabases"]} ], roles: [] });

db.createUser({user:"testUser", pwd:"passwd", roles:[{role:"read", db:"db1"},{role:"read", db:"db2"},{ role: "listDatabases", db: "admin" }]});
```

//exit as admin user and login as testUser: note the `--authenticationDatabase "admin"`

```
mongo -u "testUser" -p --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

after logging in run the command below and it should list all the databases:

```
show dbs;
```

The below will work fine even though user is not given access to `admin` database:

```
use admin;
```

But then the below will give error:

```
show collections;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related the database you are using with the `--authenticationDatabase` parameter.

You are connecting to mongo with the user of your test database who has no privileges to execute listDatabase commands.

Let's do this using the admin db as auth db

```
mongo --host 192.168.17.52 --port 27017 -u user1 -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

and then run the command

```
show dbs
```